# Moving more than one node simultaneously in contiki-os (Mobility)

Tags: java, runtime-error, mobility, contiki-ng, contiki-process

Do the lines need to be in time order? e.g.

> #node time(s) x y
>
> 0 1.1 50.26 139.3

> 1 1.1 55.26 144.3

> 0 1.3 60.26 153.1

> 1 1.3 65.26 158.1
> ...

I've only done single-node movement myself, but that's what I'd guess based
on the error you're getting.

> Hi everyone,
>
> I have been able to incorporate the mobility plugin with Cooja and am able
> to make a single node traverse a particular path (via specifying the time
> instants and coordinate positions in the '*positions.dat*' file).
>
> I now wish to enable two or more nodes to move *simultaneously* along
> different paths.
>
> Is this possible in Cooja? I have tried to write the contents of the
> *positions.dat* file in the following manner to achieve it but either
> only one node would move at a time or the '*java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Next event is in the past' *error is encountered*.*
>
> #node time(s) x y
>
> 0 1.1 50.26 139.3
>
> 0 1.3 60.26 153.1
>
> 0 1.5 70.26 174.1
>
> 0 1.7 50.26 139.3
>
> 1 1.1 55.26 144.3
>
> 1 1.3 65.26 158.1
>
> 1  1.5.26 179.1
>
> 1 1.7 85.26 144.3
>
> Any information regarding the above would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple
all the nodes which you want to move simultaneously should come together in line by line

for e.g;

0 0.0 0 0

1 0.0 80 80

0 1.0 10 10

1 1.0 70 70

0 2.0 20 20

1 2.0 60 60

0 2.0 30 30

1 2.0 50 50

0 4.0 30 20

1 4.0 50 80

if you see above example i am moving node-0 and node-1 simultaneously